# Is there a way to intercept Android Activity after it is instantiated?

Tags: android, android-activity, instantiation

Is there a way to intercept whenever the Application creates a new Activity instance?  I'm only interested in Activities belonging to the Application process not all Activities on the phone.  Is there some way to do this?  Is the Application class involved in doing this in some way?  What methods can I override to get at the Activity instance after it's been created?

Comment: Why do you need this (unless, of course, this is a commercial secret)? I can hardly imagine a case when a well-designed app needs this.

Comment: I don't know if it matters why at this point, but it's so we can design well designed applications more easily.  :-)  I have an idea and I want to explore it, and I need this feature to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just an idea - in your app you can create a base activity class so all the rest of activities are subclassed from that base activity. Then in the `onCreate()` callback you may notify some listener instance about the fact of a new app activity instance creation:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // put the code to notify a listener here
    }

}

public class YourWorkingActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }
}
```

If you use a `ListActivity` (that is common for an average Android app), then you should also create a similar BaseListActivity for it.

Most likely the best candidate for a listener would be an `Application` subclass since it is guaranteed by the OS that is will be created before any `Activity` will be instantiated.

**Warning**: you should avoid keeping a strong reference to an Activity in the listener since it will create a memory leak when the OS will try to kill that Activity (as a part of the Activity or Process life-cycle). Probably use [WeakReference](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) for this.

Comment: Yea I realize I could create a super class that could either notify about creation, or actually do the logic I plan to implement.  The reason I'm not hot on that is the exact reason you point about ListActivity vs. Activity.  It's annoying that Android architects overly rely on inheritance as a basis of reuse for their framework.  Java community stopped doing that like in 2001.  Well the EJB crowd didn't pick up on it until like 2007.  Actually I just thought of another way to deal with this issue without requiring subclassing.  Thanks.  Sometimes it just takes talking to someone.